# Hacking Prevention

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax, pdo

I have a javascript variable saved on page load which i will use later. Is it possible for a user to change this variable. I'm trying to figure out a way to, when a user inputs something, make an ajax post, and return a couple of values.

initialize() is fired when  loads so the variable quantity is obtained fairly soon into page loading.

```
function initialize() {
    quantity = parseInt(document.getElementById('shipping_quantity').value);
}
```

I then retrieve the shipping rate by querying a db with state for rate.

```
getRate(){
    var rate = '';
    $.post('getrate.php', {state: state}, function(data){
        rate = parseInt(data);
        $("input#shipping_rate").val('$' + rate);
```

Here is the getrate.php

```
<?
include_once ('includes/config.php');
$state = "OK";
if(isset($_POST['state'])){ $state = $_POST['state'];}
$con = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
$st = $con->prepare( 'SELECT rate FROM freight WHERE administrative_area_level_1 = :state' );
$st->bindParam( ':state', $state, PDO::PARAM_STR, 2 );
$st->execute();
$row = $st->fetch();
$rate = $row['rate'];
echo $rate;
?>
```

And how the shipping total is processed happens on the last part of the getRate() function

```
    var total = (rate * quantity);
    $("input#shipping_total").val('$' + total);
});
```

When I put it all together it works, but I'm concerned that the quantity may be able to be changed before the total gets calculated.

I'm considering making the shipping form post and return to itself after calculating in a functions php the shipping rates.

The example I'm looking at.

[Shopping Cart Tutorial](http://www.qualitycodes.com/tutorial.php?articleid=25&title=Tutorial-Building-a-shopping-cart-in-PHP)

Comment: Yes, the user can change absolutely anything on the page before it's submitted.  You have to check all the values on your server.

Comment: **warning** your code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Comment: Are you referring to setting async to false?  This will cause the function to block until the request is done.

Comment: You should have back-end validation, because of course through JavaScript all variables and DOM can be manipulated.

Comment: `$sql = "SELECT rate FROM freight WHERE administrative_area_level_1 = '" . $state . "'";` this basically makes the `prepare()` statement 100% useless, you're essentially treating `prepare()` just like `query()` here.

Comment: You should store order specifics server-side in session scope variables and restrict access to modifying these variables through formal submit processes.  Anything javascript is client-side is vulnerable to manipulation, so think server-side.

Comment: Gotcha! all great comments. I updated the prepare statement. Does binding the variables first make the prepare statement not useless?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible for a user to change this variable.

Probably, but more importantly, you essentially can't trust *any* information sent to you from the client. "Trust, but verify" I believe was the phrase... So in addition to anything you do client-side for convenience or UI, **you *must* double-check it server-side**.

Specifically in your case, you said you have:

```
function initialize() {
    quantity = parseInt(document.getElementById('shipping_quantity').value);
}
```

As written, that seems to either rely on a global `quantity` variable or, worse, *create* one via [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). In either case, yes, it's trivially easy for the user to change it. They can open the JavaScript console and type:

```
window.quantity = 42;
```

and press Enter.

You can defend against that and make it *slightly* harder by putting all of your code in a scoping function:

```
(function() {
    // Your code here, e.g.:

    var quantity = 0;

    function initialize() {
        quantity = parseInt(document.getElementById('shipping_quantity').value);
    }

    // ...and so on
})();
```

That at least prevents it being a global and being quite so easy to modify. But it's still really easy, all they have to do is use any modern browser, open the Dev Tools, put a breakpoint in the code, and when the breakpoint is reached, modify the value of `quantity`.

Using a scoping function is a good idea *anyway*, because globals are generally bad news. It does mean, though, that if you use old-fashioned `onXYZ` attributes to hook up event handlers, you have to switch from doing that to using DOM methods (or as you use jQuery, its [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on) function and such) instead, because `onXYZ` attributes can only call functions accessible from global scope.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make sure you have the Javascript send any prices back to the server that get used. That way, if someone does change them, it doesn't matter.

Your server will need to look up the price one time to show the user how much it is and then another time, when they submit the order, to figure out the total to bill them (or their credit card).

That way you control the price and you don't have to care if the user fools with it.